# define strongly connected components

Tags: c++, graph-theory

I have code for testing strongly connected components for graphs, and i have example of vertices and edges connection from this site: http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/bioinfo/ref/graphconncomp.html

I have copied input data there

```
   (2,1)        1
   (1,2)        1
   (3,2)        1
   (2,3)        1
   (9,3)        1
   (3,4)        1
   (5,4)        1
   (7,4)        1
   (4,5)        1
   (9,5)        1
   (1,6)        1
   (7,6)        1
   (6,7)        1
   (1,8)        1
   (9,8)        1
   (8,9)        1
   (9,10)       1
```

Here 10 vertex and 17 edges,what question is that it is from matlab where index is 1, and I want to write code in C++, and how changes vertex list? Or what could i do? Please help me, for clarification i am not asking about code, just changing from 0 based matrix to 1 based matrix, please help me.

Comment: It's not really clear what your question is, but if I understand correctly you can simply subtract 1 from every number inside the parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

MATLAB uses 1-based array indexing (the first element of the array has index 1), and C/C++ use 0-based indexing (the first element of the array has index 0).

So if you want to use the graph that is represented in MATLAB as in your post, but in C/C++, you would just need to subtract 1 from each of the indices - so for example, (2,1) would become (1,0) and (9,5) would become (8,4).